# React and Node deploy problem - Deploy succesfully but doesnt show the frontend part

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

im deploying a React and Node js website with Heroku. Heroku says that the deploy its succesfully but doesnt show on the screen the frontend part. (The favicon is shown)

This is the error that I get in the console. When I run npm start with the client in mi pc it works but not the server.
In heroku doesnt display the frontend so I dont know what about the server

```
react-dom.production.min.js:216 Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at b (react.production.min.js:18)
    at t.useMemo (react.production.min.js:23)
    at r (I18nextProvider.js:7)
    at In (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Ys (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
    at ua (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at la (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at ia (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at _r (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at Hr (react-dom.production.min.js:237)
react-dom.production.min.js:260 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at b (react.production.min.js:18)
    at t.useMemo (react.production.min.js:23)
    at r (I18nextProvider.js:7)
    at In (react-dom.production.min.js:157)
    at Ys (react-dom.production.min.js:267)
    at ua (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at la (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at ia (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at _r (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at Hr (react-dom.production.min.js:237)
```

Here you have the package json from server:

```
{
  "name": "uep",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "prueba.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "v14.15.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "server": "nodemon index.js --ignore client"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "heroku": "^7.52.0",
    "mongod": "^2.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.14",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Here you have the package.json from client

```
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "name": "uep-page",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.6.4",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "i18next": "^20.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.1",
    "react-classes": "^1.1.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.11",
    "react-pdf": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` files please?

Comment: Sure, I edited the post :)

Comment: Do you get this error in the browser console or in the Heroku console?

Comment: In the browser, Its also not rendering my html of my build run

Comment: does it work locally? do you have run them separately? Btw you are not building the front end for heroku in your package.json. You need to add  "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"  to the scripts

Comment: When I try them in my pc locally separately they work. Maybe thats the reason because its not rendering the front end part, I will try now :) Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Did you change the url correct on heroku? If you deployed frontend and backend on separated dynos, you need to call them by heroku sub domains, instead of `localhost:port` like in the local.

Comment: No! Its my first app deployment, I was doing that because is what I found on internet, I didnt know that heroku had subdomains!

Comment: Sorry misunderstood. I think the error is related to the build, does your project can run build successful on local?

Comment: If you are learning and the project is OK to publish, it would be easier for us to check your code with GitHub or something similar. As it is quite hard to guess with vast bug potential in javascript world :D

Comment: Yes :/ And the deployment its also ok, its not throwing me any error. Just when I open my heroku page it seems that its not rendering the react app

Comment: of course! This is the repo: gh repo clone valubehrend1/uepheroku

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking your code :D. Here is first comment: Add your node_modules into .gitignore (google about gitignore if you don't know). This might be the reason as I can not pull your code because the node_modules is so big, the heroku might reject to pull your git probably.

Will comment more.

Comment: Great, im checking that right now :)

Comment: I'm not sure about Heroku as I didn't use it much, but look like you need a buildpack for frontend and other for backend, and sticking both into one dyno is quite complicated, take a look at this example: https://michaellin.me/deploy-multiple-apps-in-monorepo-to-heroku/

Usually people break them up into separated repo, deploy into separated dyno on Heroku, as it is easier to configure the Procfile

Comment: For example, let alone the frontend `create-react-app`, it has this wonderful example about how to use this buildpacks, https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Comment: Really, thank you so much for your help! I will look the documentation :)

Comment: I think if you are following sort of learning course, and if they already deployed successfully, your problem might be the git. Delete your `node_modules` folder, add gitignore file, add `node_modules` into that file and try to re-deploy again.

Comment: still not working :(